# Пример JAVA кода API приложения для interactivebrokers

Tags: java, api, консоль

Здравствуйте!
Я решил попробовать создать свое API приложения для торговой площадки InteractiveBrokers. Однако подробной документации по этому поводу не нашел, а примеры, которые есть в интернете не работают. Прошу привести пример рабочего кода приложения с минимальным функционалом: подключение, получение рыночных данных по валютной паре EUR/USD.
Если кто-то знаком с этой темой, прошу помощи, потому что я в тупике.

Comment: @KukovBros Насколько я понял, они предоставляют платное API для Java. Или вы хотите парсить какие-то открытые данные?

Comment: Я установил TWS. Рыночные данные, которые меня интересуют (котировки EUR/USD) приходят в это приложение с задержкой в 15 минут. Для API приложения я хотел бы того же.
Знаю также, что у них есть пример API приложения на JAVA, но всё, что он может делать - подключаться к TWS.